# Strategies to handle frequently changing time series data using socket io and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, socket.io

I'm currently sending data to browsers using socket io. There are many devices sending data to server which is then broadcasted to browsers. The data that is pushed from server is way too frequent like once every second per device and change in data is causing angular digest loop to kick off. This I guess will have a performance impact on mobile devices. I've changed the code to push data at 10 seconds frequency from server once with most recent data for all devices. I'd like to get it more real time, is there any best practices to deal with push model and being real time within angular? I know this is a performance related question without any hard numbers - I'd be happy to run some tests to give you numbers if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$evalAsnyc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync). I pushing more than 100 update per second and there is no performance problem.